# Evento en SQL Server Profiler que muestra error en restricciones

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una aplicación en vb.net que me devuelve este error tras ejecutar un TableAdapterManager:
[image: Error en restricción]

Me gustaría saber si hay algún evento en el SQL Server Profiler que ejecuto desde el SQL Server Management Studio 2016 que me pudiera dar más datos de ese error. Si me dijera la restricciones o algo y no me diera las tres opciones ya sería un detalle.
Tengo marcados en la selección de eventos del Profiler lo siguiente:

[image: Eventos Profiler]
(El que no se ve pone SQL:BatchStarting, es por no poner otra captura).

Realmente no necesito saber cómo solucionar el problema de las restricciones, que ya estoy revisando, lo que me gustaría saber son las opciones que debo marcar en el Profiler por si en otro lenguaje u otro programa tuviera el mismo problema (de ahí que no ponga como etiqueta la del vb.net).

Gracias y un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

En el profiler hay un grupo de eventos de "Errores y Warnings", por el tipo de error que muestras, deberías seleccionar "Exception".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El tema es que te da información de la excepción pero no mucho más, por lo que deberías agregar los siguientes eventos para poder por ejemplo ver cual fue el Stored procedure o Query ejecutado antes de la excepción:

- Stored procedures

  - RPC:Completed
  - RPC:Starting

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- TSQL

  - SQL:BatchCompleted
  - SQL:BatchStaring

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota: No está de más decir que cualquier seguimiento que hagas con el profiler tendrá una impacto negativo en la performance general del motor.

Comment: Salvo el de **RPC:Starting** tenía los mismos eventos marcados y en el Profiler no me aparece nada relacionado con el error.

Comment: Acabo de probarlo en un profiler de un SQL 2012 generando un insert con un NULL en una columna NOT NULL y me capturó el evento sin problemas.  No sé que  puede ser en tu caso, te estás conectando al servidor indicado?

Comment: Patricio, sí que me estoy conectando al servidor indicado porque de hecho lo estaba inicializando nada más ejecuto el programa y sí que me muestra bien todo menos eso. Estoy casi segura que es un problema de Foreign Key, por si sirve de ayuda para mostrar el evento.